# ASP.NET Report Viewer control browser compatability issue

Tags: reporting-services, report, viewer

We render `SSRS` reports in `ASP.NET` forms using `Report Viewer` control (Remote Mode). The report renders fine in `IE6 +` but it does not render the following elements in `Google Chrome`.

1. Date Picker does not show up in the Parameter prompt
2. Tool Bar is distorted and does not show zoom, print and find options.

Can anyone throw pointers on the cross-browser compatibility of `Report Viewer` control (V `8.0`) otherwise we will have to do parameter capturing in `ASPX` itself

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the Report Viewer control is only compatible with IE6,7,8.

This page elaborates on it a bit but many of the features are only compatible with IE:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251673%28VS.80%29.spx

Also, a workaround for the Chrome distortion issues can be found here:  http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2009/08/13/ReportViewer-control-toolbar-in-Google-Chrome-browser.aspx

Comment: Both links are broken

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Brendan. I found that through MSDN site (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511.aspx) about the compatability issues.

But for Chrome distortion, i tried the suggestion mentioned in the mazsoft site. but i have not been successful so far. i will keep trying and looking for other options.

Answer (score 0):

To Fix date issue

http://www.rajbandi.net/post/2011/04/03/Fixing-SSRS-Report-Viewer-control-date-picker-in-Google-chrome.aspx

To Fix chrome Distortion,

http://www.rajbandi.net/post/2011/04/03/Fixing-ReportViewer-control-toolbar-in-Google-Chrome.aspx

Comment: Both links are broken.