# SSRS date-picker is invisible in Google Chrome, not working in Opera/IE?

Tags: reporting-services, cross-browser, ssrs-2008

I'm integrating SSRS reports(developed in VS 2008 vs. 9.0 ), and when I load it into the browser with Chrome, I get this:

[image]

There's no date-icon!

In Opera it shows, but doesn't work:

[image]

How do I figure out how to 1.) get it to work correct .  2) Make it visible in Chrome

I found a site talking about it( [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/a96537e3-0945-4046-816b-5eb0d8875dd3/) ) , but it only hhas a dead-link ( http://www.rajbandi.net/ )

Is it just me or is this a complex issue to fix? Any tips appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Report Viewer control browser compatability issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716053/asp-net-report-viewer-control-browser-compatability-issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this post will be helpful for you?
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/504567/Print-button-Date-picker-in-SSRS-Reports-for-Non-I

Comment: Hi Roman, that tutorial is a little confusing - but i think its helpful

Comment: I agree with you, but it's good because have a source code and the only solution that I found. Actually not only with date-picker problems in not IE browsers. About browser support for SSRS you can read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511(v=sql.100).aspx . In our company we developed all custom controls and buttons for print\export functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The supposedly dead link ([rajbandi.net](https://rajbandi.net/)) was accessible at the time of writing this post; I'm putting its contents here for use if the link is down again:

---

**Fixing SSRS Report Viewer control date picker in Google chrome**
Author: Raj Bandi
April 3, 2012
https://rajbandi.net/2012/04/03/fixing-ssrs-report-viewer-control-date-picker-in-google-chrome/

SSRS Report Viewer control works well in IE6+ but has some known compatibility issues with other major browsers(Firefox, Chrome etc.) around date picker and print button.

For more information read this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251673.aspx

I am presenting a simple solution to fix date picker issue in Chrome with  a combination of some server side code and Client side JQuery script.

**Server Side Code**

1) Add the below code in the page/control file in which the reportviewer control resides

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="DatePickers" runat="server" />
```

2) Add the below code in the code behind file of page/control in which the reportviewer control resides(.Net 2.0 version)

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    DatePickers.Value = string.Join(",",(new List(GetDateParameters()).ToArray()));
}
private IEnumerable GetDateParameters()
{
    // I'm assuming report view control id as reportViewer
    foreach (ReportParameterInfo info in reportViewer.ServerReport.GetParameters())
    {
        if (info.DataType == ParameterDataType.DateTime)
        {
            yield return string.Format("[{0}]",info.Prompt);
        }
    }
}
```

**Client Side Code**

1) Add the below script in the html head section

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($.browser.webkit)
    {
        $($(":hidden[id*='DatePickers']").val().split(",")).each(function(i, item) {
            var h = $("table[id*='ParametersGrid'] span").filter(function(i) {
            var v = "[" + $(this).text() + "]";
            return (v != null && v.indexOf(item) >= 0);
        })
        .parent("td").next("td").find("input")
            .datepicker({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: '/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.calendar.gif',
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in Chrome, an option could be just to show the date excluding the time. This make more sense to the end user.

```
//Update the dates
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=text]').each(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace('12:00:00 AM', ''));
    })
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but adding this would make pagination functionality fail. In fact when we try to change anything (format/value) for the date textboxes, the pagination was not working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Removing current account/people and adding new account/people on chrome worked for me.

[image]