# SSRS ReportViewer in MVC - Missing Date Picker drop down in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, reportviewer

There seems to be a common knowledge of the issue where the SSRS ReportViewer (Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common) does not appear to render the Date-Picker calendar drop-down icon for non-IE browsers:

[As per this Stack Overflow question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862481/ssrs-date-picker-is-invisible-in-google-chrome-not-working-in-opera-ie)

However all the solutions I have found (as per the link) are aimed at Web Forms based applications. I have a an MVC project with the same issue and am wondering if anyone else out there has come across a fix for this?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Intergrating SSRS reports into MVC is not very common.  There are two ways I know of to do this.  Is your MVC apps controller action redirecting to a classic aspx page? No? Then, are you using something like https://reportviewerformvc.codeplex.com/?

Comment: Thanks for the response Troy... Sorry, yes we are using the ReportViewerForMVC which seems to do most of the work - apart from allow us to drop-down a date picker. We have decided to fix a few (other) IE related issues and are forcing users to use IE now. Seems to be working so far.

Comment: IE only works for now. 

I did see that the GitHub issue reporting for that project mentions that the date picker was fixed in version 0.5?  [here](https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer/issues/)

Comment: The fact that [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ssrs-report-fix/fjbdfjiheheafbioiejbdpalmojkeobk) to fix SSRS exists, demonstrates to me that it IS possible to fix this issue using ONLY client-side javascript.

Comment: Thanks Troy - very interesting, however it may be a bit too much work for us to recreate that to work within the application (i.e. so we dont have to install and maintain this on any chrome browser that happens to want to use the reporting app). Thanks again though!